# button for add div on form

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello I learn the code and I have a problem: I have a form with one or more numbers and I like what is composed as many times as I press the add_button button and I want to be able to remove a div with the delete button ...
here is my code for those who have ideas :

```
<div class="w-full dis-none js-show-service">
    <div class="wrap-input100 input100-select bg1">
        <div class="wrap-input100 input100-select bg1">
            <span class="label-input100">Techno Garentie d'Origine *</span>
            <div>
                <select class="js-select2" id="select3" name="service">
                    <option value="Solaire">Solaire</option>
                    <option value="Hydro">Hydraulique</option>
                    <option value="Eolien">Eolienne</option>
                    <option value="BioMasse">BioMasse</option>
                </select>
                <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="wrap-input100 input100-select bg1">
            <span class="label-input100">Provenance Garentie d'Origine *</span>
            <div>
                <select class="js-select2" id="select2" name="service">
                    <option value="europe">Europe</option>
                    <option value="allemagne">Allemagne</option>
                    <option value="autriche">Autriche</option>
                    <option value="belgique">Belgique</option>
                    <option value="chypre">Chypre</option>
                    <option value="croatie">Croatie</option>
                    <option value="danemark">Danemark</option>
                    <option value="espagne">Espagne</option>
                    <option value="estonie">Estonie</option>
                    <option value="finlande">Finlande</option>
                    <option value="France">France</option>
                    <option value="irlande">Irlande</option>
                    <option value="islande">Islande</option>
                    <option value="italie">Italie</option>
                    <option value="lituanie">Lituanie</option>
                    <option value="luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                    <option value="norvege">Norvege</option>
                    <option value="pays-bas">Pays-Bas</option>
                    <option value="republique-tcheque">Republique-Tcheque</option>
                    <option value="slovenie">Slovénie</option>
                    <option value="suede">Suède</option>
                    <option value="suisse">Suisse</option>
                </select>
                <div class="dropDownSelect2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="wrap-contact100-form-range">
            <span class="label-input100">Pourcentage D'energie Verte *</span>
            <div class="contact100-form-range-value">
                 <span id="value-upper">50</span>%
                  <input type="text" name="from-value">
                  <input type="text" name="to-value">
            </div>
            <div class="contact100-form-range-bar">
                  <div id="filter-bar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="suppr_button">-</button>
    </div>
    <button class="add_button">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You tagged your question with `php` and `javascript` - where is the related code?

Comment: What is your exact question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: my code is too long i just send the part do i want to add with add_button but the function for that will be on php or js

Comment: I do not know how to go about adding this div loop through the button

Comment: what `"div loop"`? Where is the javascript? Do you mean the entire code is to be repeated??

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an example. I mean, that's the way.

I am trying to create a `<div>` dynamically, with an appended `<div>` inside.

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
 iDiv.id = 'block';
 iDiv.className = 'block';
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
```

-You can take a template from my example.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the question despite it not being very clear - presumably you wish to repeat the entire DIV ( as depicted in the question ) and ALL of it's contents when you click the `add` button and remove newly added nodes when you click the remove button. The one issue with the original code is the use of `ID` attributes which MUST be unique for the document to remain valid and for Javascript functions to operate as intended - so the following replaces the ID with a classname of the same value which you will need to account for in any other Javascript or css routines you may have.

In Javascript you can use `node.cloneNode(true|false)` to clone a node and optionally ALL of it's contents too. The following makes use of this feature and assigns event listeners to all newly created buttons which, when clicked, will further replicate/modify the DOM.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Repeat DIV on button click</title>
        <style>
            .js-show-service{
                margin:1rem auto;
                border:1px solid red;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                padding:1rem;
            }
            .clone{
                border:1px solid blue!important
            }
            input,button,select{padding:0.5rem}
            button{min-width:10%;clear:none;float:none;margin:0.25rem;}

            .clone:before{
                content:attr(data-clone);
                color:white;
                background:black;
                padding:0.5rem;
                width:2rem;
                height:2rem;
                text-align:center;
                margin:0;
                left:-1rem;
                top:-0.5rem;
                position:relative;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',e=>{

                let parent=document.body;
                let i=parent.querySelectorAll('div.js-show-service').length;


                const clonediv=function( n ){
                    let clone=n.cloneNode( true );
                        clone.classList.add('clone');
                        clone.dataset.clone=i;

                        clone.querySelector( '.add_button' ).addEventListener('click',function(e){
                            clonediv( this );
                        }.bind( clone ) );

                        clone.querySelector( '.suppr_button' ).addEventListener('click',function(e){
                            removediv( this )
                        }.bind( clone ) );

                        clone.querySelectorAll('input').forEach( inp => {if( inp.value!=='' )inp.value='';} )
                        clone.querySelectorAll('*').forEach( el=>{ if( el.hasAttribute('id') )el.removeAttribute('id') })


                    parent.appendChild( document.createComment( 'Clone: '+i ) );
                    parent.appendChild( clone );
                    clone.scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth',block:'end'})
                    i++;
                    return clone;
                }
                const removediv=function( n ){
                    parent.removeChild( n );
                }

                Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'button' ) ).forEach( function(bttn){
                    bttn.addEventListener('click',function(event){
                        if( this.className=='add_button' )clonediv( this.parentNode );
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Repeated content using javascript</h1>


        <!-- repeat ALL of the following -->

        <div class='w-full dis-none js-show-service'>
            <div class='wrap-input100 input100-select bg1'>
                <div class='wrap-input100 input100-select bg1'>
                    <span class='label-input100'>Techno Garentie d'Origine *</span>
                    <div>
                        <select class='js-select2' name='service'>
                            <option value='Solaire'>Solaire
                            <option value='Hydro'>Hydraulique
                            <option value='Eolien'>Eolienne
                            <option value='BioMasse'>BioMasse
                        </select>
                        <div class='dropDownSelect2'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class='wrap-input100 input100-select bg1'>
                    <span class='label-input100'>Provenance Garentie d'Origine *</span>
                    <div>
                        <select class='js-select2' name='service'>
                            <option value='europe'>Europe
                            <option value='allemagne'>Allemagne
                            <option value='autriche'>Autriche
                            <option value='belgique'>Belgique
                            <option value='chypre'>Chypre
                            <option value='croatie'>Croatie
                            <option value='danemark'>Danemark
                            <option value='espagne'>Espagne
                            <option value='estonie'>Estonie
                            <option value='finlande'>Finlande
                            <option value='France'>France
                            <option value='irlande'>Irlande
                            <option value='islande'>Islande
                            <option value='italie'>Italie
                            <option value='lituanie'>Lituanie
                            <option value='luxembourg'>Luxembourg
                            <option value='norvege'>Norvege
                            <option value='pays-bas'>Pays-Bas
                            <option value='republique-tcheque'>Republique-Tcheque
                            <option value='slovenie'>Slovénie
                            <option value='suede'>Suède
                            <option value='suisse'>Suisse
                        </select>
                        <div class='dropDownSelect2'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class='wrap-contact100-form-range'>
                    <span class='label-input100'>Pourcentage D'energie Verte *</span>
                    <div class='contact100-form-range-value'>
                        <span class='value-upper'>50</span>%
                        <input type='text' name='from-value' />
                        <input type='text' name='to-value' />
                    </div>
                    <div class='contact100-form-range-bar'>
                        <div class='filter-bar'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--<button class='suppr_button'>-</button>-->
            </div>


            <button class='add_button'>+</button>
            <button class='suppr_button'>-</button>
        </div>

        <!-- END repeated content -->



    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am considering you are adding newly created div's inside any `div`, like adding to `myDiv`

```
<div id="myDiv"> </div>
```

On click of Add button, you can add divs like below,

```
<button class="add_button" onclick="addDiv()">+</button>

<script>
function addDiv() {
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.id= "someID";
  newDiv.className  = "class";
  document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(newDiv);
}

</script>
```